# Independence property of conditional expectation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to understand the example 2.3.6 of the Steve Shreve book which is related to the following definition:

Definition. Let's say $X$ depends on the n+1..N coin tosses so it doesn't depends on the first n coin tosses. Let's assume that we want to take

$$
\mathbb{E}_n[X] = E[X]
$$

Example. In his example we draw consecutively a coin with probability $p=2/3$ alternatively $q=1/3$

[image]

And in his example he argues that $S_2/S_1$ does not depend on the first coin tosses

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}_1[\frac{S_2}{S_1}](H) &= \frac{2}{3} \frac{S_2(HH)}{S_1(H)} + \frac{1}{3} \frac{S_2(HT)}{S_1(H)} = \frac{2}{3} \frac{16}{8} + \frac{1}{3} \frac{4}{2}  = \frac{3}{2} \\
\mathbb{E}_1[\frac{S_2}{S_1}](T) &= \frac{3}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

We see that $E_1[S_2/S_1]$ does not depend on the first coin toss (is not really random) and in fact is equal to

$$
E \frac{S_2}{S_1} = \frac{2}{3} \cdot 2 + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{2}
$$

And this is the last part that I don't understand for me the expectation should be written as

$$
\begin{aligned}
E \frac{S_2}{S_1} &= \frac{S_2(HH)}{S_1(H)} p(HH) + \frac{S_2(HT)}{S_1(H)} p(HT) + \frac{S_2(TH)}{S_1(T)} p(TH) + \frac{S_2(TT)}{S_1(T)} p(TT) = \frac{7}{6}\\
&= \frac{16}{8} (\frac{2}{3})^2 + \frac{4}{8}\frac{2}{3} \frac{1}{3} + \frac{4}{8}\frac{2}{3} \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2}  (\frac{1}{3})^2\\
&= \frac{64}{72} + \frac{8}{72} + \frac{8}{72} + \frac{4}{72} \\
&=\frac{84}{72} = \frac{7}{6}
\end{aligned}
$$

Which is numerically incorrect but I don't understand how come ?

Comment: I'm not sure how you got $\frac 89$ as the value of that expression.  We have $\frac{S_2(HH)}{S_1(H)} p(HH) = 2 \left(\frac 23\right)^2 = \frac 89$, so adding in the other terms would necessarily have to give something bigger than $\frac 89$.

Comment: Yes I did a mistake it should be 7/6 which is still not correct

Comment: You're going to have to show the details of that computation because I think $\frac 76$ is still not the right value.  When I evaluate that expression, I get $\frac 32$.

Comment: I wrote the complete derivation above

Comment: You've used $S_1(T) = 8$ in the third term in the sum, it should be $2$

Comment: Thanks I was too fast ^^